# Texlive-common and lang-norwegian not cooperating

Tags: 13.10, language-support, sublime-text, texlive

I got sublime and texlive working, but I'm norwegian and want to write in norwegian so I'm trying to install that language. But, this is what I get:

```
texlive-lang-norwegian : Krav: texlive-base (>= 2009-1)
                         Krav: texlive-common (>= 2009-1)
```

It's norwegian, but it says it can't install. Any good ideas?

My version of texlive-common:

```
Package: texlive-common
Priority: optional
Section: tex
Installed-Size: 296
Maintainer: Debian TeX Maintainers <debian-tex-maint@lists.debian.org>
Architecture: all
Source: texlive-base
Version: 2009-11+squeeze1
Depends: tex-common (>= 2.0)
Conflicts: texlive (<< 2009-1), texlive-base (<< 2009-1), texlive-base-bin (<< 2008), texlive-bibtex-extra (<< 2009-1), texlive-binaries ............
```

Comment: Sorry folks, I had added some extra ppa's so I unchecked them, updated, installed European-package and can now chose "norsk" (norwegian). :)

Comment: Post the answer to your own post and mark it as correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry folks, I had added some extra ppa's so I unchecked them in Software Update. Now I'm only using the originally repositories from Ubuntu. Then I did

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-european
```

to install the European package. Now I think I can use norsk (actually still working on eiditing a template that use american-apa and other stuff).

Comment: Sorry for short answer, but I thought it was enough (because of the comment I got before)